# Use sendmailR with Windows error

Tags: r, windows-firewall, sendmailr

I am using sendmailR package to automate my email sending tasks. My code is like:

> require(sendmailR)
>
> from <- "test1@sample.com"
>
> to <- 'test2@sample.com'
>
> subject <- "Email Subject"
>
> body <- "Email body."
>
> mailControl=list(smtpServer="mail.sample.com")
>
> sendmail(from=from,to=to,subject=subject,msg=body,control=mailControl)

I have no problem running the above code using my 64 digits, outlook 2007, windows 7 machine, but get this error message once I running the same thing on a 32 digits, outlook 2010, windows xp machine:

> Error in socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) : 
>     cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In socketConnection(host = server, port = port, blocking = TRUE) :
>     mail.sample.com:25 cannot be opened

anyone has any idea how this happened?

Comment: Please check the firewall and network configurations. Are they equal on booth servers?

Comment: Can you tell me how to check this setting?

Comment: Sorry, I use more Linux and MacOSX computer. I suggest to use a different tag.

Comment: Please go check method to DIAGNOSE mail server connection.